# Why can't sbt 0.11 sbt-idea plugin generate a project correctly in my case? (details inside)

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-idea

I've installed sbt 0.11 sbt-idea as its documentation says. It seems to work, but...

1. It doesn't see a project's name (even having the project named, Idea project generated is named `default-11eed1`)
2. It fails downloading some jars it wants

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
:: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.2!commons-codec.jar(src)
:: org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5!test-interface.jar(src)
:: org.scala-tools.sbt#compiler-interface;0.11.0!compiler-interface.jar(src)
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a specific project name, I think you need to use a "full" build configuration, rather than a "light" configuration. SBT automatically assigns a project ID if you only have a build.sbt file, and this is used as the IntelliJ module name.

`sbt-idea` automatically downloads the source JARs for your library dependencies, and for SBT itself. Not all libraries are published with sources, in those cases this warning is shown.